# Can't use Swype after connecting and disconnecting my Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, swype

I'm testing my new Samsung luetooth keyboard with my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 and discovering some peculiarities.

Connecting the keyboard was relatively simple. However, when I don´t use the tablet in conjunction with the bluetooth keyboard, I use the Swype option on the screen. Once I've connected the keyboard to the tablet for a bit, when I disconnect it, it doesn't go back to using Swype. Not only that, but I can't change the settings to use Swype manually. I can only begin to use Swype again when I restart the device.

Has anyone encountered and overcome this?